# Cloudflare redirect domain

Tags: redirect, dns, cloudflare, http-redirect

I'm trying to redirect domainA.com to domainB.com. Both domains are managed with Cloudflare. I've tried using Page Rules for domainA to redirect all requests to domainB.com. However, I've also read that domainA needs to have DNS records of some sort through Cloudflare but I'm not entirely sure how to configure these? This redirect is the only thing I'm using domainA for, there's no content hosted on it at all.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue? The answers are of no real use to me because I also have a domain without any DNS that should just function as a redirect.

Comment: @RubenSzekér check the new answer which may be of some help to you.

Answer (score 4):

A combination of a mock `CNAME` record and a Page Rule will make it.

1. Go to your source domain's DNS settings page.
2. Create a `CNAME` record for the `@` (root domain). Point it to some subdomain, it doesn't have to exist as the page rule will kick in before the DNS record resolves.

[image]

3. Go to your source domain's Page Rules page.
4. Create a new page rule redirecting all requests to your domain as necessary (choose 301/302 - whichever makes sense in your case).

[image]

---

5. Give it some time and confirm `https://source-domain.com` redirects to `https://target-domain.com`.

Repeat steps 1 - 5 for the `www` subdomain if you want `www.source-domain.com` to redirect too (which is often the case).

Comment: how do i add a redirect from example.com/any_url_slug to https://www.example.com/any_url_slug in cloudfare, is there any page rule for this? how can we achieve this?

currently i am able to do like this , example.com/* to https://www.example.com/ but not going to the required destination, instead going to the home page - > "/"

Comment: @RohanDevaki Set a forwarding page rule 301 Redirect

from

```http://example.com/*```

to ```http://example.com/$1``` it will just work like a charm dont forget the ```$1```

Answer (score 1):

Set a forwading page rule 301 Redirect

from

```
http://domainA.com/*
```

to  `http://domainB.com/$1`

Comment: how do i add a redirect from example.com/any_url_slug to https://www.example.com/any_url_slug in cloudfare, is there any page rule for this? how can we achieve this?

currently i am able to do like this , example.com/* to https://www.example.com/ but not going to the required destination, instead going to the home page - > "/"

Comment: Set a forwarding page rule 301 Redirect

from

```http://example.com/*```

to ```http://example.com/$1``` it will just work like a charm dont forget the ```$1```

Answer (score 0):

In 6 steps you have new domain.

1. In your control panel, select the domain
2. Click on page rules
3. In 'url match' set example: (domainA.com/*)
4. Setting is 'forwarding url' with 302 (test) or 302 (production)
5. And finnaly set the new url ex: (http://domainB.com)
6. Save and deploy

for full documentation see this:
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-Configuring-URL-forwarding-or-redirects-with-Cloudflare-Page-Rules

Comment: how do i add a redirect from example.com/any_url_slug to https://www.example.com/any_url_slug in cloudfare, is there any page rule for this? how can we achieve this?

currently i am able to do like this , example.com/* to https://www.example.com/ but not going to the required destination, instead going to the home page - > "/"